# Owncloud does not show files, that are uploaded via SSH

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, wget, cloud

After spending 10 Hours configuring owncloud on Fedora 24 (because of NO documentation and proper tutorial), I finally got OwnCloud up and running perfectly.

My owncloud configuration files are in

`/usr/share/owncloud` and

`/etc/owncloud` and my data is stored in

`/home/owncloud/ocdata/root/files`

When I upload something via SSH with `curl` or `wget` command  on my server and move it to  `files` directory, this files doesn't show up in owncloud web interface!

Any help would be great.
Thanks

UPDATE1: when I

`cd /home/owncloud/ocdata/root/files/Documents` 
and

`ls -lha`

I get the following

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4.0K Jul 22 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 apache apache 4.0K Jul 22 17:45 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  36K Jul 22 16:59 Example.odt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 683M Jul 22 17:02 test.rar
```

my problem is, test.rar won't show up in owncloud web interface but Example.odt Does show up!

Comment: Did you check the ownership and the permissions of the files after you move them to their final resting place ? Do they differ from the files you can see ?

Comment: @MelBurslan Thanks man for the answer, I updated my question!

Answer (score 2):

Since OC 9.0(?) Filesystem checks are disabled by default for more performance.

Check and maybe change your config.php to

```
'filesystem_check_changes' => 1,
```

https://doc.owncloud.com/server/7.0EE/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you need to refresh the ocdata file. Procedure below:

- First `cd` into the `occ` folder, which can be found with:

  `find / -name "occ" 2>/dev/null`
- Then:

  `sudo -u www-data php occ files:scan --all`

Source : https://bartsimons.me/manually-add-files-to-owncloud/